# Transistor Amplifier circuit to generate regulated output

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, voltage-regulator

I am using below circuit to generate Vo=5V and Vs=8.5V(+/-0.5V tolerance),I need to supply 100mA load current. So i kept R6=50 ohm
My cicuit is working fine with above configuration but when i want to increase the load current to 200mA by changing RL to 25 ohms, the circuit not able to maintain regulation and the Vo is dropping below 3V. Do you know why this is happening ? How to select NPN transistor ? what all factors to consider ? how much hfe(current gain) required. I need to supply 100mA but the circuit should work at 150mA or even 200mA.

[image]

Comment: You state in the text that you have a 1k resistor at the output of the opamp - it isn't shown in the schematic and is not needed nor wanted.

Comment: Yes I have placed in the simulation which is not shown here. Do you mean its not required to place that resistor ?

Comment: It is probably preventing enough base current to drive 200mA. Measure the opamp output.

Comment: I have removed the resistor. Now the load current is 175mA and the output voltage 4.45V for 25ohm load resistor

Comment: Add another transistor to form a Darlington configuration.

Comment: Show your simulation circuit with the components that are fitted. A circuit that doesn't 100% represent your actual circuit is no use.

Comment: @Andyaka please check now, I have added my simulation circuit

Comment: Remove C2 and R8 - they are hurting, not helping.

Comment: @KevinWhite can you explain how C2 and R8 are hurting this circuit ??

Comment: Remove 3x10ohms in collector. Their drops doesn’t allow to reach 5V on output at 200mA current.

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast - R8 reduces the drive to the transistor. C2 increases the phase shift around the loop potentially causing instability. The more relevant question is why you felt it necessary to put them in the circuit?

Comment: Why did you choose that opamp?

Comment: @KevinWhite I took available opamp in LTspice for simulation purpose. I would like to change it to OPA197

Answer (score 2):

You edited the question, introducing many more resistors, and even a couple of capacitors, most of which are unnecessary, problematic or redundant. My original answer, below, addresses the *original* circuit.

---

Given the components and values you *originally* mentioned, I think your circuit should work. However there's a chance you've got an outlier transistor, with particularly low current gain, in which case what I say below might help. In any case, you'll learn something.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPFdXw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Base current will have to be high enough to produce the required 200mA emitter current. By placing a 1kΩ resistor in the path of base current, you have severely limited the amount of base current that is achievable.

Given the transistor's current gain of, say, \$\beta=100\$, for emitter current \$I_E\approx 200mA\$, you require base current \$I_B\$:

$$ I_B \approx \frac{I_E}{\beta} \approx \frac{200mA}{100} \approx 2mA $$

That base current has to pass through RB, 1kΩ, and that resistance will develop a voltage:

$$ V_{RB} = I_B \times R_B = 2mA \times 1k\Omega = 2V $$

Looking at the above schematic, where these conditions are all shown, the potential difference across RB is indeed 2V. After accounting also for the drop of 0.8V from base to emitter, you can see that the op-amp is required to produce 7.9V at its output, for 5V to appear at the emitter.

That's perilously close to the power supply potential, and there's a good chance the op-amp (even though it claims to have a "rail-to-rail" output), can't do that while sourcing 2mA.

Since Q1 is an emitter follower, RB is not necessary, and you could dispense with it altogether:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz5aYp.png)</sup>

Now the op-amp output doesn't have to get anywhere near its positive supply potential. However, this does mean that the op-amp output will be forced to +0.8V if ever the emitter is shorted to ground. If that's at all likely to happen, then to protect the op-amp, as a compromise RB should be closer to 100Ω than 1kΩ.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This will certainly help. what will happen when emitter sees +/-10V from load side due to transient ? I want to Analyse this circuit when there is transient for few micro seconds and emitter sees +/-10V.

Comment: I  have implemented the changes as you suggested. I have placed 100 ohm resistor at the  output of opamp and shorted the emitter to ground to see how much current that flows through 100 ohms. The current through 100 ohms is 50mA, output voltage of opamp 6.4V and the base voltage is 1.4V. Do you know why this is happening ? ideally when emitter grounded the base voltage should be 0.8V right ?

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast If you force emitter potential above the base, nothing happens until about 5V difference, then the base-emitter junction (a zener diode) conducts, and the base starts to follow it, but 5V lower. If you force emitter potential below the base, the base is also dragged with it, but 0.7V higher. In both cases RB can save the op-amp and the transistor.

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast 50mA through 100Ω will develop 5V, so that 6.4V-to-1.4V drop is to be expected.

Comment: Isnt it 1.4V Vbe is too much ? I am using 2N5550 transistor for simulation. Also there is a 5V drop across RB when i short emitter to ground, so that Pd across Rb = 5*50mA=250mW. I need to choose my RB accodingly, is it correct ?

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast 1.4V sounds a bit high, I would expect less than 1V across the junction at 50mA. Maybe the transistor is damaged, or maybe it's just a quirk of that model. The base-emitter junction is just a diode, so whatever V-I characteristics you expect from a diode you can expect in that junction too.

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast As I mentioned in my answer, I thought your transistor must be an outlier in some respect, because it should easily have handled 200mA. It sounds like you may have fried it a little. You should be more worried about power \$I_C \times V_{CE}\$ than anything. I believe it would be rated at 500mW or so, max, though I haven't checked the datasheet.

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast As an example, if you find 300mA flowing out of the emitter, with the emitter at 0V, that means you have the full 8V supply between collector and emitter, and the transistor is dissipating \$0.3A \times 8V = 2.4W\$, which will easily kill a small transistor in just a couple of seconds.

Comment: ok thanks, I think thats what happening. can you tell me what will happen when emitter sees +/-10V transient from load. what happens to this circuit and how to protect ?

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast I think that's a whole new question, there's lots to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Lose resistors R1, R2, R13, and R20, and upgrade the transistor with a PD of 1-watt or more.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the resistor from op-amp output(or change to 10ohm).

The transistor power dissipation is Pd= (8.5V-5V)*0.2A=0.7W, so you are at the edge of 2n4401 limit (0.6W).

So consider transistor with higher Pd rating.

Comment: As this is all in simulation (and thus probably doesn't model self-heating), I doubt this is an issue. You're right that a 2N4401 is not a good choice for this circuit in reality, though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything too complex, though a TL431 would be helpful. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqawJh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$Q_1\$ is a simple comparator. \$R_1\$ guarantees a reasonable current for the TL431. The rest is basic. When the output first starts up near zero volts, \$Q_1\$ is disabled (so is the TL431) and \$R_1\$ turns on \$Q_2\$ and \$Q_3\$ to supply current into \$C_1\$. Eventually, the \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ divider turn on \$Q_1\$ sufficiently that the TL431 gets its needed current and sets up the comparator. At that point the loop is active and the output should settle out at the designed output. Adjust \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ as needed or use a potentiometer.

I believe it should be able to handle the currents you indicated. I haven't built this, though. So I may have missed something.

Here's a simulation from LTspice where I make sudden variations on the load from \$100\:\text{mA}\$ to \$500\:\text{mA}\$:

[image]